# how to install SML-New jersey .93 version?

Tags: sml

I am trying to find installer for  sml nj .93 version,and also how to install it .I have been advised to use this version rather than sml nj 110 version

Comment: What operating system are you trying to install under?

Comment: i have been trying to install on windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

SMLNJ version 0.93 was released in 1993. It is [available](http://www.smlnj.org/NEWS/93-README.html) for historical purposes.

```
SML/NJ 0.93 has been tested on these machine/OS combinations:
Sun M680x0/SunOS (x >= 2)
HP M680x0/HPUX[6,7,8] **
NeXT M68040/NeXTStep[2.0,3.0]
Apple M680x0/AUX[3.0]
Apple M680x0/MacOS
Sun SPARCstation/SunOS[4.1.1, 4.1.3]
DEC MIPS/ULTRIX[UWS4.2]
DEC Mach
MIPS MIPS/RiscOS[4.51,4.52]
SGI MIPS/IRIX[4.0.x]
Sony MIPS/Sony-News
IBM RS6000/AIX[3.2]
Sequent I386/DYNIX3
Intel I[386,486]/BSD/MACH
```

It was never tested on any version of Microsoft Windows including Windows 3.1 and Windows NT 3.1 which would have been available at the time. I recommend pursuing additional information in regards to the recommendation.

It might be possible to run SMLNJ 0.93 in a virtual machine running BSD. It is highly unlikely to run natively under Windows 8.1.